# Windows Vista shows error "A specified privilege does not exist" when running any administrative tool/process

Tags: windows-vista, privileges

I'm troubleshooting a PC running Windows Vista Ultimate Version 6.0. When I run programs such as regedit, msconfig, or do things like try to disable Microsoft Security Essentials's Real-time protection (for Combofix), I get this error:

[image]

I ran Combofix in Safe Mode and this is its log:

```
ComboFix 13-11-23.02 - PaoLo 11/24/2013  12:07:01.2.2 - x86 NETWORK
Microsoft® Windows Vista™ Ultimate   6.0.6000.0.1252.1.1033.18.2038.1567 [GMT 8:00]
Running from: c:\users\PaoLo\Downloads\ComboFix.exe
.
.
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((   Other Deletions   )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
.
.
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\extensions\iafkwov0@oauy-.net
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\extensions\iafkwov0@oauy-.net\bootstrap.js
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\extensions\iafkwov0@oauy-.net\chrome.manifest
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\extensions\iafkwov0@oauy-.net\content\bg.js
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\extensions\iafkwov0@oauy-.net\content\zy.xul
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\extensions\iafkwov0@oauy-.net\install.rdf
c:\windows\system32\FlashPlayerApp.exe
c:\windows\system32\X86
.
.
(((((((((((((((((((((((((   Files Created from 2013-10-24 to 2013-11-24  )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
.
.
2013-11-24 04:14 . 2013-11-24 04:14 --------    d-----w-    c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\temp
2013-11-24 04:14 . 2013-11-24 04:14 --------    d-----w-    c:\users\Default\AppData\Local\temp
2013-11-24 01:17 . 2013-11-08 01:15 7772552 ----a-w-    c:\programdata\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Definition Updates\{C6699626-0560-45D6-8328-1F2B489BE5F1}\mpengine.dll
2013-11-22 05:45 . 2013-11-08 01:15 7772552 ----a-w-    c:\programdata\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Definition Updates\Backup\mpengine.dll
2013-11-15 14:44 . 2013-11-15 14:44 --------    d-----w-    C:\MSI
2013-11-06 00:03 . 2013-11-06 00:03 650936  ----a-w-    c:\programdata\Microsoft\eHome\Packages\SportsTemplate\SportsTemplateCore\Microsoft.MediaCenter.Sports.UI.dll
2013-11-03 06:35 . 2013-11-03 06:35 --------    d-----w-    c:\program files\iPod
2013-11-03 06:35 . 2013-11-03 06:37 --------    d-----w-    c:\programdata\188F1432-103A-4ffb-80F1-36B633C5C9E1
2013-11-03 06:35 . 2013-11-03 06:37 --------    d-----w-    c:\program files\iTunes
2013-11-03 05:58 . 2013-11-03 05:58 --------    d-----w-    c:\program files\Common Files\Java
2013-11-03 05:56 . 2013-11-03 05:56 94632   ----a-w-    c:\windows\system32\WindowsAccessBridge.dll
2013-11-02 11:35 . 2013-10-26 01:54 272496  ----a-w-    c:\program files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\components\browsercomps.dll
2013-11-02 11:32 . 2013-11-02 11:32 243128  ----a-w-    c:\windows\system32\drivers\dtsoftbus01.sys
2013-11-02 11:31 . 2013-11-02 11:32 --------    d-----w-    c:\program files\DAEMON Tools Lite
.
.
.
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((   Find3M Report   ))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
.
2013-11-19 10:21 . 2009-10-03 02:10 230048  ------w-    c:\windows\system32\MpSigStub.exe
2013-09-27 01:53 . 2013-09-27 01:53 214696  ----a-w-    c:\windows\system32\drivers\MpFilter.sys
.
.
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((   Reg Loading Points   ))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
.
.
*Note* empty entries & legit default entries are not shown 
REGEDIT4
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\shelliconoverlayidentifiers\DropboxExt1]
@="{FB314ED9-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FB314ED9-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}]
2013-06-13 23:00    130736  ----a-w-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.19.dll
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\shelliconoverlayidentifiers\DropboxExt2]
@="{FB314EDA-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FB314EDA-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}]
2013-06-13 23:00    130736  ----a-w-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.19.dll
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\shelliconoverlayidentifiers\DropboxExt3]
@="{FB314EDB-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FB314EDB-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}]
2013-06-13 23:00    130736  ----a-w-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.19.dll
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\shelliconoverlayidentifiers\DropboxExt4]
@="{FB314EDC-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FB314EDC-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}]
2013-06-13 23:00    130736  ----a-w-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\DropboxExt.19.dll
.
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"uTorrent"="c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" [2013-09-01 1130576]
"DAEMON Tools Lite"="c:\program files\DAEMON Tools Lite\DTLite.exe" [2013-10-28 3675352]
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"tsnp2std"="c:\windows\tsnp2std.exe" [2007-05-12 270336]
"snp2std"="c:\windows\vsnp2std.exe" [2007-09-28 344064]
"Persistence"="c:\windows\system32\igfxpers.exe" [2008-09-09 154136]
"HotKeysCmds"="c:\windows\system32\hkcmd.exe" [2008-09-09 178712]
"GrooveMonitor"="c:\program files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveMonitor.exe" [2009-02-26 30040]
"FixCamera"="c:\windows\FixCamera.exe" [2007-07-11 20480]
"APSDaemon"="c:\program files\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\APSDaemon.exe" [2013-04-21 59720]
"QuickTime Task"="c:\program files\QuickTime\QTTask.exe" [2013-04-30 421888]
"SunJavaUpdateSched"="c:\program files\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe" [2013-07-02 254336]
"Adobe ARM"="c:\program files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe" [2013-04-04 958576]
"iTunesHelper"="c:\program files\iTunes\iTunesHelper.exe" [2013-10-18 152392]
"MSC"="c:\program files\Microsoft Security Client\msseces.exe" [2013-10-23 948440]
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\system]
"SoftwareSASGeneration"= 3 (0x3)
.
[hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\SharedTaskScheduler]
"{1984DD45-52CF-49cd-AB77-18F378FEA264}"= "c:\program files\Stardock\Fences\FencesMenu.dll" [2010-06-22 202088]
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\MsMpSvc]
@="Service"
.
[HKLM\~\startupfolder\C:^ProgramData^Microsoft^Windows^Start Menu^Programs^Startup^McAfee Security Scan Plus.lnk]
path=c:\programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\McAfee Security Scan Plus.lnk
backup=c:\windows\pss\McAfee Security Scan Plus.lnk.CommonStartup
backupExtension=.CommonStartup
.
[HKLM\~\startupfolder\C:^Users^PaoLo^AppData^Roaming^Microsoft^Windows^Start Menu^Programs^Startup^Dropbox.lnk]
path=c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Dropbox.lnk
backup=c:\windows\pss\Dropbox.lnk.Startup
backupExtension=.Startup
.
[HKLM\~\startupfolder\C:^Users^PaoLo^AppData^Roaming^Microsoft^Windows^Start Menu^Programs^Startup^OneNote 2007 Screen Clipper and Launcher.lnk]
path=c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\OneNote 2007 Screen Clipper and Launcher.lnk
backup=c:\windows\pss\OneNote 2007 Screen Clipper and Launcher.lnk.Startup
backupExtension=.Startup
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\Adobe ARM]
2013-04-04 21:06    958576  ----a-w-    c:\program files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\APSDaemon]
2013-04-21 13:43    59720   ----a-w-    c:\program files\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\APSDaemon.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\DAEMON Tools Lite]
2013-10-28 08:29    3675352 ----a-w-    c:\program files\DAEMON Tools Lite\DTLite.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\ehTray.exe]
2006-11-02 12:34    125440  ----a-w-    c:\windows\ehome\ehtray.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\Facebook Update]
2012-07-12 05:00    138096  ----atw-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Facebook\Update\FacebookUpdate.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\FileHippo.com]
2012-11-23 08:22    307712  ----a-w-    c:\program files\FileHippo.com\UpdateChecker.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\Google Update]
2009-08-31 05:19    133104  ----atw-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\googletalk]
2011-12-19 07:39    3817472 ----a-w-    c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Google\Google Talk\googletalk.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\iTunesHelper]
2013-10-18 21:31    152392  ----a-w-    c:\program files\iTunes\iTunesHelper.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\PC Suite Tray]
2009-11-11 02:57    1451520 ----a-w-    c:\program files\Nokia\Nokia PC Suite 7\PCSuite.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\QuickTime Task]
2013-04-30 19:59    421888  ----a-w-    c:\program files\QuickTime\QTTask.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\shared tools\msconfig\startupreg\SunJavaUpdateSched]
2013-07-02 01:16    254336  ----a-w-    c:\program files\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run-disabled]
"IgfxTray"=c:\windows\system32\igfxtray.exe
"HDAudDeck"=c:\program files\VIA\VIAudioi\VDeck\VDeck.exe -r
"Adobe Reader Speed Launcher"="c:\program files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"
"NBKeyScan"="c:\program files\Nero\Nero8\Nero BackItUp\NBKeyScan.exe"
"GrooveMonitor"="c:\program files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveMonitor.exe"
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\svchost]
bthsvcs REG_MULTI_SZ    BthServ
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\active setup\installed components\{10880D85-AAD9-4558-ABDC-2AB1552D831F}]
2008-08-22 06:11    451872  ----a-w-    c:\program files\Common Files\LightScribe\LSRunOnce.exe
.
Contents of the 'Scheduled Tasks' folder
.
2013-11-24 c:\windows\Tasks\Adobe Flash Player Updater.job
- c:\windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe [2012-07-07 02:34]
.
2013-11-23 c:\windows\Tasks\FacebookUpdateTaskUserS-1-5-21-812886578-3759993032-3091145522-1000Core.job
- c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Facebook\Update\FacebookUpdate.exe [2011-12-23 05:00]
.
2013-11-24 c:\windows\Tasks\FacebookUpdateTaskUserS-1-5-21-812886578-3759993032-3091145522-1000UA.job
- c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Facebook\Update\FacebookUpdate.exe [2011-12-23 05:00]
.
2013-11-24 c:\windows\Tasks\GoogleUpdateTaskUserS-1-5-21-812886578-3759993032-3091145522-1000Core.job
- c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe [2009-08-31 05:19]
.
2013-11-24 c:\windows\Tasks\GoogleUpdateTaskUserS-1-5-21-812886578-3759993032-3091145522-1000UA.job
- c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe [2009-08-31 05:19]
.
2013-11-24 c:\windows\Tasks\User_Feed_Synchronization-{CE3A4985-B6F6-42AC-B6C6-70724635B444}.job
- c:\windows\system32\msfeedssync.exe [2006-11-02 09:45]
.
.
------- Supplementary Scan -------
.
uStart Page = hxxp://isearch.babylon.com/?babsrc=HP_ss_btis2&mntrId=34A9001966CBF5F8&affID=119529&tsp=4924
uDefault_Search_URL = hxxp://search.certified-toolbar.com?si=41460&tid=2937&bs=true&q=
mStart Page = hxxp://search.easylifeapp.com/?pid=720&src=ie1&r=2013/03/09&hid=1458095096&lg=EN&cc=PH
mSearch Bar = hxxp://search.certified-toolbar.com?si=41460&tid=2937&bs=true&q=
uInternet Settings,ProxyOverride = *.local
uSearchAssistant = hxxp://feed.snapdo.com/?publisher=SnapdoOCYB&dpid=SnapdoOCYB&co=PH&userid=e64b9f36-b430-79c3-f4ce-a16432f24e02&searchtype=ds&q={searchTerms}&installDate=22/08/2013
uSearchURL,(Default) = hxxp://www.google.com/search?q=%s
IE: E&xport to Microsoft Excel - c:\progra~1\MICROS~2\Office12\EXCEL.EXE/3000
IE: Search the Web - c:\program files\SweetIM\Toolbars\Internet Explorer\resources\menuext.html
TCP: DhcpNameServer = 124.106.4.2 124.106.5.2
FF - ProfilePath - c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\3yfh5i7f.default\
FF - prefs.js: browser.search.defaulturl - hxxp://search.easylifeapp.com/?pid=720&src=ff2&r=2013/03/09&hid=1458095096&lg=EN&cc=PH&l=1&q=
FF - ExtSQL: !HIDDEN! 2009-09-03 08:07; {20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b}; c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Windows Presentation Foundation\DotNetAssistantExtension
FF - user.js: yahoo.homepage.dontask - true);user_pref(yahoo.ytff.general.dontshowhpoffer, true);user_pref(extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.babTrack, affID=100888
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.babExt - 
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.srcExt - ss
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.id - 34a90308000000000000001966cbf5f8
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.hardId - 34a90308000000000000001966cbf5f8
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.instlDay - 15364
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.vrsn - 1.5.3.17
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.vrsni - 1.5.3.17
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.vrsnTs - 1.5.3.1714:06
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.prtnrId - babylon
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.prdct - BabylonToolbar
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.aflt - babsst
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.smplGrp - none
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.tlbrId - base
FF - user.js: extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.instlRef - sst
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.tlbrSrchUrl - 
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.id - 34a90308000000000000001966cbf5f8
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.appId - {C26644C4-2A12-4CA6-8F2E-0EDE6CF018F3}
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.instlDay - 15881
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.vrsn - 1.8.21.5
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.vrsni - 1.8.21.5
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.vrsnTs - 1.8.21.520:33
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.prtnrId - delta
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.prdct - delta
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.aflt - babsst
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.smplGrp - none
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.tlbrId - base
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.instlRef - sst
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.dfltLng - en
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.excTlbr - false
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.ffxUnstlRst - true
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.admin - false
FF - user.js: extensions.delta_i.babTrack - affID=119529&tsp=4924
FF - user.js: extensions.delta_i.babExt - 
FF - user.js: extensions.delta_i.srcExt - ss
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.autoRvrt - false
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.rvrt - false
FF - user.js: extensions.delta.newTab - false
.
- - - - ORPHANS REMOVED - - - -
.
MSConfigStartUp-KiesPDLR - c:\program files\Samsung\Kies\External\FirmwareUpdate\KiesPDLR.exe
MSConfigStartUp-KiesPreload - c:\program files\Samsung\Kies\Kies.exe
MSConfigStartUp-KiesTrayAgent - c:\program files\Samsung\Kies\KiesTrayAgent.exe
MSConfigStartUp-Messenger (Yahoo!) - c:\progra~1\Yahoo!\MESSEN~1\YahooMessenger.exe
MSConfigStartUp-Pokki - %LOCALAPPDATA%\Pokki\Engine\LaunchDeskband.dll
MSConfigStartUp-RIMBBLaunchAgent - c:\program files\Common Files\Research In Motion\USB Drivers\RIMBBLaunchAgent.exe
MSConfigStartUp-SweetIM - c:\program files\SweetIM\Messenger\SweetIM.exe
.
.
.
**************************************************************************
.
catchme 0.3.1398 W2K/XP/Vista - rootkit/stealth malware detector by Gmer, http://www.gmer.net
Rootkit scan 2013-11-24 12:14
Windows 6.0.6000  NTFS
.
scanning hidden processes ...  
.
scanning hidden autostart entries ... 
.
scanning hidden files ...  
.
.
c:\users\PaoLo\AppData\Local\Temp\catchme.dll 53248 bytes executable
.
scan completed successfully
hidden files: 1
.
**************************************************************************
.
--------------------- LOCKED REGISTRY KEYS ---------------------
.
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-812886578-3759993032-3091145522-1000_Classes\CLSID\{7B8E9164-324D-4A2E-A46D-0165FB2000EC}]
@Denied: (Full) (Everyone)
"scansk"=hex(0):5c,9f,ea,bb,82,eb,c7,a0,9e,7e,ec,3e,06,d3,ec,e7,d0,32,3f,b6,9a,
   ba,3b,dc,0b,41,5e,8e,65,04,8d,c6,fa,61,80,15,f2,13,9c,c8,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
.
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-812886578-3759993032-3091145522-1000_Classes\CLSID\{8aa74d11-5ab9-4973-8943-e1e5cbcb9e50}]
@Denied: (Full) (Everyone)
"Model"=dword:00000050
"Therad"=dword:0000001f
"MData"=hex(0):73,d5,cf,b8,a4,07,89,80,31,e4,35,6b,2a,ca,fe,43,b6,1f,81,1f,5a,
   1b,4d,36,46,8f,3c,f2,5c,68,ee,21,46,8f,3c,f2,5c,68,ee,21,46,8f,3c,f2,5c,68,\
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0001\AllUserSettings]
@Denied: (A) (Users)
@Denied: (A) (Everyone)
@Allowed: (B 1 2 3 4 5) (S-1-5-20)
"BlindDial"=dword:00000000
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0002\AllUserSettings]
@Denied: (A) (Users)
@Denied: (A) (Everyone)
@Allowed: (B 1 2 3 4 5) (S-1-5-20)
"BlindDial"=dword:00000000
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0003\AllUserSettings]
@Denied: (A) (Users)
@Denied: (A) (Everyone)
@Allowed: (B 1 2 3 4 5) (S-1-5-20)
"BlindDial"=dword:00000000
.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0004\AllUserSettings]
@Denied: (A) (Users)
@Denied: (A) (Everyone)
@Allowed: (B 1 2 3 4 5) (S-1-5-20)
"BlindDial"=dword:00000000
.
--------------------- DLLs Loaded Under Running Processes ---------------------
.
- - - - - - - > 'Explorer.exe'(1984)
c:\program files\Stardock\Fences\FencesMenu.dll
c:\program files\stardock\fences\DesktopDock.dll
.
Completion time: 2013-11-24  12:16:56
ComboFix-quarantined-files.txt  2013-11-24 04:16
.
Pre-Run: 3,903,877,120 bytes free
Post-Run: 3,599,085,568 bytes free
.
- - End Of File - - E17E3920A390678D554E1659CCE00E8E
5C616939100B85E558DA92B899A0FC36
```

I'm stumped. Please help, thank you.

Comment: have you disabled UAC? if not have you run the tools as admin? Note that I am not suggesting you disable UAC. I have found myself, that disabling it causes more problems than leaving it at default settings.

Comment: @FrankThomas I can't check if UAC is on or off because when I click "Turn User Account Control on or off" from User Accounts, nothing happens. But I believe it is currently on, as the owner of this computer wouldn't mess with these kind of settings. **I believe any application that requires Admin rights won't run.**

Comment: @d4ryl3 - You have serious permissions problems.  Unless you have a working Administrator account you are simply out of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound I was afraid of that, since this account is already an Administrator. Can't even check System Restore out.

Comment: @d4ryl3 - If your unable to use the default Administrator account you are out of luck.  The fact the user account is an Administrator isn't important.

Comment: @Ramhound I've restarted it in Safe Mode and now every admin stuff works. I enabled the default Admin account, rebooted, and now logged in as it. How do I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: @d4ryl3 - The simplest way is to create a new user.  Your current user has major permission problems, unless I know what permission changes you did to it, hard to tell you how to fix it.